# Android device connected via USB is added to audio group

Tags: usb, android

I am trying to work remotely with an android mobile device connected to `ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` machine.
The problem is that the device is not identified correctly.
It seems that the device is recognized as an audio device by unknown reason.

This happens only when I access the machine remotely.
There is no problem when I access the machine directly.

How can I work around this situation?

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0184 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5182 Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (MTP mode)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0049 SiGma Micro USB Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/004`

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 189, 3  3월  7 11:53 /dev/bus/usb/001/004
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding a rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d`, a file named `99-android.rules`, which contains

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0660",
GROUP="plugdev", SYMLINK+="android%n"
```

From the bug report, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libmtp/+bug/1863239, it seems that there is a rule that adds the device to audio group by mistake. (Maybe rule 69)

My goal here is just to have the device in `plugdev` group, so I make the rule priority level 99. (When I tried 51, it didn't work. Possibly the rule 69 might be the cause of problem.)